# Beginner: img src syntax? Specific example

Tags: html

I followed the guide [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp) and I've done some Googling to no avail. Would someone mind pointing out the embarrassing blunder in my implementation here?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="bonsai_tree.jpg" alt="tree" width="511" height="482">
    </body>
</html>
```

The image is in the same directory as the html and I've triple-checked the name. I get a broken link image box when I render the page.

Thanks, and if I'm not following the proper question-asking protocol, please let me know! First-timer here...

EDIT: For what it's worth, I'm using a school-provided appliance running Linux. I don't believe this should be a problem, though I suppose I could be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure it's jpg and not jpeg?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your syntax. Check the case of letters in the name. `bonsai` !== `Bonsai`.

Comment: Checked both. It's not jpeg and the cases match. Thanks, though.

Comment: Try `src="../bonsai_tree.jpg"` or `src="/bonsai_tree.jpg"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the page, and then View Source on the html in the browser. Find the link to the image and click it- the error that it gives will tell you the problem.

It sounds like it's most likely permissions. Check the file permissions on the image file. It sounds like they're too low for you to view the file in the browser. I believe you need `604` permissions for it to be able to be used.

In a Linux terminal in that folder, run `chmod 604 bonsai_tree.jpg` to set the permissions correctly.

Comment: This was it! Thanks so much! For the record, I changed the permissions to 644 based on direction from my class.

Comment: That should also be fine for your project, it just needs `604` at minimum.

Answer (score 3):

Ive been there before :-)

Usually the syntax you have is correct is the picture is in the same file, just double check the spelling.
Here's a link to a fully detailed way on how to get a picture showing on your web page :
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Yahya, but I've checked the name a good 5-6 times now and it's still good :). I also checked that link out before I posted the question...

Answer (score 1):

Bring up the image correctly in another tab in your browser.

Then go to the tab with your HTML, right click on the broken image, select "View Image".  Compare the bad URL of this tab with the good URL of the other tab and your problem will be obvious.

Comment: What if he wants a relative URL as opposed to an absolute one?

Comment: He does, but the right-click will absolute-ize the URL and he can see how that process goes wrong.

Comment: I checked it and even tried using the long name: file:///home/*****/vhosts/localhost/public/bonsai_tree.jpg. When I use the long name, the broken file icon goes away, but still no tree (?)

Comment: Use File->Open and open the file that way.  Now observe the URL in the location bar.  **Note**: the HTML file and the JPG better be in the same directory...